# Poincaré surface of section of the kicked rotator

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, hamilton-equations

Wikipedia's article about the kicked rotator says that it's Hamiltonian is
\begin{equation}
    H(p,q,t)=\frac{1}{2}p^2+K\cos(q)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-n)
\end{equation}
and it's Poincaré surface of section is
\begin{align}
  q_{n+1}&=q_n+p_{n+1} \\
  p_{n+1}&=p_n+K\sin(q_n).
\end{align}

I solved Hamilton equations and got
\begin{equation}
    \dot{q}=p, \qquad \dot{p}=K\sin(q)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-n).
\end{equation}
How do I construct this Poincaré surface of section to get the discrete equations from the continuous ones?

What is the difference between this and the standard map? (In the standard map I need to take $p$ and $q$ modulo $2\pi$ and in the kicked rotator only the $q$ is modulo $2\pi$?)

And how can I construct its phase space plot? (Is it possible to do this in LaTeX?)

Thanks

Comment: This was also cross-posted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256144/poincaré-surface-of-section-of-the-kicked-rotator

Answer (score -1):

Kicked rotor is inherently a two-dimensional system, and one can choose a line as Poincaré section, such as a specific angle, but doing so doesn't have much significance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).